# Display highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript. I have been trying to add a highlighting feature on a web interface but struggling to get it to work properly. The code below is what I have gotten so far, it allows users to select text -> then popover buttons appear for choosing which class the selected text belong to -> selected text are highlighted. But these highlighted text are not saved properly, as a result, they are not displayed correctly when the "show highlights" button is clicked (as seen in the screenshots).

In this example I want to see

> Class 1: Barrister Constance Briscoe
>
> Class 2: police

when "show highlights" is clicked. Ultimately, these highlighted text along with their classes are to be saved as dicts for future (sorry I am only familiar with Python).

Screenshot #1:
[image: highlighting screenshot]
Screenshot #2:
[image: show highlights screenshot]

```
require(['jquery-noconflict'], function(jQuery) {
  var $ = jQuery || window.jQuery;
  var lastSelection;
  document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
    lastSelection = window.getSelection()
  });
  var showBtn = document.getElementById('show_highlights_btn');
  var highlights = document.createElement("highlights") 

  function getRightClick(e) {return rightclick; // true or false
    }

    function getSelectionText() {return text;
    }


  $('.main_area').mousedown(function(event) {
    $('body').attr('mouse-top',event.clientY+window.pageYOffset);
    $('body').attr('mouse-left',event.clientX);

    if(!getRightClick(event)) {
            $('.entity_types').hide(); 
            document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); 
        }
  });

  $('.main_area').mouseup(function(event) {
    if (lastSelection.toString().length > 1 && !getRightClick(event) ){
      $('.entity_types').css({
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: event.clientY + 15,
        left: event.clientX + 10
      });

      $('.entity_types button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var category = $(this).text();
        var txt = document.createTextNode(category  + ": "  + selectedText);
        highlights.appendChild(txt);
      });
    }
  });

  showBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //<div id="selected_highlights"></div>
    var selected_highlights = document.getElementById("selected_highlights");
    selected_highlights.appendChild(highlights);
  });

});
```

**UPDATE:** I have managed to make the "show highlights" working, but somehow the latest highlight is showing twice..

```
  showBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log("display buttons");
    var selected_highlights = document.getElementById("selected_highlights");

    /** first remove current text **/
    while (selected_highlights.hasChildNodes()) {
      selected_highlights.removeChild(selected_highlights.lastChild);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < highlights.innerHTML.length; i++) {
      console.log('display highlight');
      selected_highlights.appendChild(highlights.childNodes[i]);
      selected_highlights.appendChild(br());
    }
```

Comment: Im lost I did not understand you

Comment: Basically I want to save all highlighted texts and display all of them when a "show highlights" button is clicked. But as you can see from the 2nd screenshot, they are not correctly displayed.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this is how to highlight text in HTML.

```html
<span style="background-color:#FFFF00">HIGHLIGHTED TEXT</span>
```

So, because you have your highlight colors divided into classes, you assign classes to each span.

```css
.class1{
background-color:red;
}
.class2{
background-color:green;
}
.class3{
background-color:blue;
}
.class4{
background-color:turquoise;
}
.class5{
background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<span class='class1'>CLASS 1</span>
<span class='class2'>CLASS 2</span>
<span class='class3'>CLASS 3</span>
<span class='class4'>CLASS 4</span>
<span class='class5'>CLASS 5</span>
```

Now, you need to get the selected text.

```js
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
  console.log(getSelectionText());
};
```

```css
.class1{
    background-color:red;
    }
    .class2{
    background-color:green;
    }
    .class3{
    background-color:blue;
    }
    .class4{
    background-color:turquoise;
    }
    .class5{
    background-color:purple;
    }
```

```html
<span class='class1'>CLASS 1</span>
    <span class='class2'>CLASS 2</span>
    <span class='class3'>CLASS 3</span>
    <span class='class4'>CLASS 4</span>
    <span class='class5'>CLASS 5</span>
```

You then get that text, and highlight it.
I did this in this example by replacing the word with a span, but it's not the best way. For example, highlighting "phrase here" will highlight the first instance of "phrase here" in the book. This is outside of this current problem though, so I'll leave that to you.

```css
.class1{
background-color:red;
}
.class2{
background-color:green;
}
.class3{
background-color:blue;
}
.class4{
background-color:turquoise;
}
.class5{
background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<span class='class1'>CLASS 1</span>
<span class='class2'>CLASS 2</span>
<span class='class3'>CLASS 3</span>
<span class='class4'>CLASS 4</span>
<span class='class5'>CLASS 5</span>
```

Now, you need to get the selected text, and highlight it.

```js
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    console.log(text);
    return text;
}
function highlight(){
  if(getSelectionText().split(" ").length>1){
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.replace(getSelectionText(), "<span class='class1'>"+getSelectionText()+"</span>");
}else{
console.log("TOO SHORT!");
}
}
```

```css
.class1{
    background-color:red;
    }
    .class2{
    background-color:green;
    }
    .class3{
    background-color:blue;
    }
    .class4{
    background-color:turquoise;
    }
    .class5{
    background-color:purple;
    }
```

```html
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor. Sit amet amet. Lorem purus risus sed molestie aliquam. A ac nulla sit lacus turpis. Eleifend vel nascetur orci wisi eget. Laoreet nibh non nibh mi eget. Ligula consectetuer mauris ornare turpis molestiae magna mauris risus venenatis amet nascetur. Leo sed aliquam. Aliquam vivamus wisi at at vehicula. In quam praesent pharetra amet arcu. Lectus morbi velit vitae eligendi nibh imperdiet praesent suspendisse. Id scelerisque vel semper arcu dolor posuere nec elementum. Consequat bibendum fermentum. Nunc sed enim. Neque fermentum in. Nulla ornare imperdiet non dolor cursus condimentum ac tellus. Auctor vestibulum etiam scelerisque ullamcorper ut in inceptos porttitor. Commodo morbi turpis. Arcu dictum nostra nunc velit et ultrices nec suspendisse urna quam sed. Maecenas eget feugiat.</p>
<button onclick="highlight()">HIGHLIGHT</button>
```

Let the user choose a class, and save it to a dictionary.

```js
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    console.log(text);
    return text;
}
function highlight(){
document.getElementById("dict").innerHTML+=encodeURIComponent(getSelectionText())+", ";
  if(getSelectionText().split(" ").length>1){
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.replace(getSelectionText(), "<span class='"+document.getElementById("class").value+"'>"+getSelectionText()+"</span>");
}else{
console.log("TOO SHORT!");
}
}
```

```css
.class1{
    background-color:red;
    }
    .class2{
    background-color:green;
    }
    .class3{
    background-color:blue;
    }
    .class4{
    background-color:turquoise;
    }
    .class5{
    background-color:purple;
    }
```

```html
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor. Sit amet amet. Lorem purus risus sed molestie aliquam. A ac nulla sit lacus turpis. Eleifend vel nascetur orci wisi eget. Laoreet nibh non nibh mi eget. Ligula consectetuer mauris ornare turpis molestiae magna mauris risus venenatis amet nascetur. Leo sed aliquam. Aliquam vivamus wisi at at vehicula. In quam praesent pharetra amet arcu. Lectus morbi velit vitae eligendi nibh imperdiet praesent suspendisse. Id scelerisque vel semper arcu dolor posuere nec elementum. Consequat bibendum fermentum. Nunc sed enim. Neque fermentum in. Nulla ornare imperdiet non dolor cursus condimentum ac tellus. Auctor vestibulum etiam scelerisque ullamcorper ut in inceptos porttitor. Commodo morbi turpis. Arcu dictum nostra nunc velit et ultrices nec suspendisse urna quam sed. Maecenas eget feugiat.</p>
<input id="class" value="class1" /><button onclick="highlight()">HIGHLIGHT</button>
<p id="dict"></p>
```

HOPE THIS HELPS!

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks very much Kento. It is not really what I am looking for. As you can see from my code, I already have `var selectedText` which is the highlighted text and `var category` which is the corresponding class of the highlights. I want to display them using `showBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {})`, which requires saving in e.g. a list of dicts (I am using Python lang here) or other data structures that is good in JS..

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps you, I had made a fiddle for a friend a few days ago,

Maybe not your exact use case, but logic might help you.

```js
function highlightSearch() {

  var text = ["JavaScript", "is", "or"];
  
  var sampleText = document.getElementById('searchtext').innerHTML;
  //alert(sampleText);
  
  for(var i = 0; i<text.length; i++){
   //console.log(text[i]);
    var re = new RegExp(text[i], 'g');
    sampleText = sampleText.replace(re, '<a href="#"><span class="highlighte-text">'+text[i]+'</span></a>');
    
    
  }
  
  document.getElementById('searchtext').innerHTML = sampleText;
  
  
}
```

```css
div {
    padding: 10px; 
}

.highlighte-text{
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div><h2>Find and highlight 'javascript', 'is' & 'or' text in document</h2>
<form action="" method="" id="search" name="search">

<input name="searchit" type="button" value="Search" onclick="highlightSearch()">
</form></div>
<div id="searchtext">
JavaScript is the programming language of the Web. The overwhelming majority of
modern websites use JavaScript, and all modern web browsers—on desktops, game
consoles, tablets, and smart phones—include JavaScript interpreters, making Java-
Script the most ubiquitous programming language in history. JavaScript is part of the
triad of technologies that all Web developers must learn: HTML to specify the content
of web pages, CSS to specify the presentation of web pages, and JavaScript to specify
the behavior of web pages. This book will help you master the language.
If you are already familiar with other programming languages, it may help you to know
that JavaScript is a high-level, dynamic, untyped interpreted programming language
that is well-suited to object-oriented and functional programming styles. JavaScript
derives its syntax from Java, its first-class functions from Scheme, and its prototypebased
inheritance from Self. But you do not need to know any of those languages, or
be familiar with those terms, to use this book and learn JavaScript.
The name "JavaScript" is actually somewhat misleading. Exceptfor a superficial syntactic
resemblance, JavaScript is completely different from the Java programming language.
And JavaScript has long since outgrown its scripting-language roots to become
a robust and efficient general-purpose language. The latest version of the language (see
the sidebar) defines new features for serious large-scale software development.
</div>
```